# How to disable div after check checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi to all i'm new to web designing.Please help me any one.
I have two html pages.
In first one contains two checkboxes and second contains two divs one is left side and another one is right side.
Now i want in first page any one checkbox is checked and another one is automatically goes to disable.Now second page one div is automatically goes to disable mode means any functionality in not work on that div.I mean if LHS checkbox is checked in first page so LHS div is only work in second page.

It is possible or not?

I'm using HTML,bootstrap and jquery.

Comment: Please share relevant code, also share what you have tried.

Comment: You include together those page into single one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be better if **you can share your relevant code**, here i make illustration for example purpose like so :

Assumed this is our **HTML** code :

```
<!-- first page -->
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" data-target="firstDiv" />First
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" data-target="secondDiv" />Second
  <hr/>
<!-- Second page -->
  <div id="firstDiv" class="myDiv">HEllo 1st DIV</div>
  <div id="secondDiv" class="myDiv">HEllo 2nd DIV</div>
```

And here is **JS** code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.myCheckbox', function () {
  var target = $(this).data('target');    
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#' + target).addClass('disabled');
  else $('#' + target).removeClass('disabled');
});
```

And one more, **CSS** code for disable class :

```
.myDiv {
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  margin:2px;
}
.disabled {
  background-color:grey;
  color : #C0C0C0;
  opacity : 0.1;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/bg38qq2d/3/)** - disabled all functionality on disabled div(event listener mostly)

I defined `data-target` attribute on checkbox itself to target specified `div` matched with `ID`.

Comment: i placed accordion code in second page.i checked check box after accordion also disable but accordion functionality is working.Disable means it changed color only.I want accordion functionality also disable.

Comment: Here is updated link to disable functionality http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/bg38qq2d/3/ for attached class disabled

Comment: Thank you it's working fine.I have one doubt i'm created one table with 2 values(shared above code).In this values i selected one name is LHS and One name is RHS.Now I click next button it goes to second page.In this page names are divide to Previous selection means LHS and RHS.It is possibel?

Comment: click next button and 2nd page appeared on same page or using normal link to go to the 2nd page? You meant select both name, then divide those name? did't get it about divided name part.

Comment: Two pages are different.Next button in first page, next button through go to second page.And i select first name is LHS automatically second selects RHS.After click next button it displays second page with names LHS and RHS.i.e, my requirement.

Comment: Yes you can, but you need to store those name into like "LHS, RHS" into localstorage if the second page appeared on normal refreshed, and split the value itself into two part.

Comment: Hi,you are attached updated link in that code i added third page in that page add two more div's with same id's now i checked check box it disabled only second page div not third page div.why? id's are same.

Comment: I see, those problem because if you are using same ID name for multiple element, then it will only occur on first matched element only. To solve, change the ID into CLASS definition. Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/bg38qq2d/6/

Comment: data-target accept class name? i tried this scenario but it is not working.

Comment: `data-target` is just user defined attributes, our implementation decide which one to display. In this case, in JS part need to change `#` into `.` notation. And in HTML part remove id and leave only class attribute

Comment: Glad to hear that, if this answer useful then please accept this as an answer on left side answer's post with `right mark`. This used as a references for other OP to solve his/her problem. Anyway, glad to hear that and you're welcome mate!

Comment: Hi,LHS and RHS names dividing is not possible?

Comment: why not possible? can you explain what the problem outcome?